# Start teamspeak and connect to server using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, teamspeak

Normally u can start teamspeak and auto connect to an server using cmd and type `"C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak 3 Client\ts3client_win64.exe" "ts3server://my.ip"` .

I already tried `Process.Start(Chr(34) + "C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak 3 Client\ts3client_win64.exe" + Chr(34) + " " + Chr(34) + "ts3server://my.ip" + Chr(34))` but this doesn't work.

Any ideas how to get it working? Maybe start cmd.exe with it?

*I am new to stackoverflow, feel free to comment so I can improve my asking skills.*

Comment: _"this doesn't work"_ -> What happens?  Any errors etc?

Comment: "System cannot find the file." But the path + file exists right there. Teampeak also starts if I just use `Process.Start("C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak 3 Client\ts3client_win64.exe")`. I think it try to start both "files", but the second one is no file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Process.Start`, when called with one argument, tries to start the exact process specified.  Since you're passing arguments, it fails to find the file to start it.

In order to pass arguments, you need to use [a different overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx), passing the arguments separately:

```
Process.Start("C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak 3 Client\ts3client_win64.exe", "ts3server://my.ip")
```

This also means you don't need to double up on all the quotes as you were doing on the command line.

Comment: Perfect! :) Thx alot for ur quick respond!